# WordPress Plugin to scrape the BBCs most popular section

Tags: wordpress, simple-html-dom, domparser

I am trying to scrape the most popular section into a WordPress plugin from the bbc.co.uk/news/ website. I currently have the following code:

```
<?php 
/*
    Plugin Name: BBC Scrape
    Description: Reprints the BBCs Most popular stories 
Author: The Health Check Team
    Version: 0.1-alpha
 */

include('simple_html_dom.php');        
$articles = array();  
getArticles('http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/');      
function getArticles($page) {  
    global $articles;  
  <br>
    $html = new simple_html_dom();  
    $html->load_file($page);  

$items = $html->find('div[class=livestats livestats-tabbed tabbed most-popular]');    

foreach($items as $post) {  
    # remember comments count as nodes  
    $articles[] = array($post->children(3)->outertext,  
                        $post->children(4)->first_child()->outertext,  
            $post->children(5)->first_child()->outertext);  
} 

}
?>
```

I have before used such functions as `wp_remote_get`, however that just got the whole site. And I couldn't filter it down to just the most-popular section using DOM Parse. 
The Error I am getting in this code is a function `find()` error in the `simple_html_dom.php` document which is unedited>

I basically don't understand how I can get the most-popular section of the bbc.co.uk/news section on it's own.

Comment: I'll guess BBC won't like what you trying to archive.

Comment: I understand that, it's just a learning technique i'm trying to do. As it will help me how to use the DOM Parse and simple_html_dom.php file. I'm not using it for my benefit or gain.